No se guardan los estilos al convertir codigo html en PDF
Lo que sucede es que tengo una función, que guarda el contenido de un div (container-original) y lo almacena en formato PDF, en una ruta del servidor. Hasta aca funciona todo bien, el problema es que el archivo pdf que se genera, no toma los estilos de mi .css, ni los importados de bootstrap. He llegado a conseguir que tome los estilos, borrando la ruta de mi .css y borrando el import de BS. El problema es que lo que más necesito son los estilos que aplica bootstrap, ya que tiene muchas clases.
Intente usando muchas librerias: dompdf, html2pdf, fpdf, y varias más. La ultima que estoy usando es mPDF pero con todas me sucede el mismo problema con los estilos.
Trabajo con html, css, javascript y php.
Este es el script de mi archivo principal:
<script>
    function guardarComoPDF() {
        const element = document.getElementById('container-original');
        const id_inquilino = <?php echo $id_persona; ?>;
        const id_recibo = <?php echo $id_clave_recibo; ?>;

        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "guardar_pdf3.php",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            html_content: element.innerHTML,
            id_inquilino: id_inquilino,
            id_recibo: id_recibo
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error("Error en la petición AJAX:");
                console.error("Estado: " + textStatus);
                console.error("Error lanzado: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

Y este es el codigo php de guardar_pdf3.php:
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

use Mpdf\Mpdf;

// Ruta al directorio temporal personalizado
$ruta_temporal = '/home/bdsd44777/public_html/tar1.0/tmp/mpdf';

// Crear una instancia de mPDF con un directorio de archivos temporales personalizado
$mpdf = new Mpdf([
    'tempDir' => $ruta_temporal,
]);

if(isset($_POST['html_content']) && isset($_POST['id_inquilino']) && isset($_POST['id_recibo'])) {
    $html_content = $_POST['html_content'];
    $id_inquilino = $_POST['id_inquilino'];
    $id_recibo = $_POST['id_recibo'];

    // Definir contenido HTML
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html_content);

    // Guardar el PDF en el servidor
    $ruta_base = "../images/wsp/$id_inquilino/$id_recibo/";
    $nombreArchivo = $id_recibo . '.pdf';

    if (!file_exists($ruta_base)) {
        mkdir($ruta_base, 0777, true);
    }

    $archivo_destino = $ruta_base . $nombreArchivo;

    if (!file_exists($archivo_destino)) {
        $mpdf->Output($archivo_destino, 'F'); // Guardar el PDF en el servidor
        echo 'Archivo guardado correctamente en el servidor.';
    } else {
        echo 'El archivo ya existe en el servidor.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error: Datos incompletos recibidos.';
}
?>

Como dije anteriormente, el pdf se guarda y todo, pero lo que no agarra son los estilos. Solamente agarr estilos en linea si es que no estoy importando ningun archivo .css o el de bootstrap (el BS import o en local pasa igual)

La librería Mpdf no acepta hojas de estilo. Una solución es incluir todo el css de bootsrap en , ya sea o bien añadiéndolo directamente a tu html, o para que quede un poco mejor, en un archivo .php y añadiéndolo mediante un include.

Así es. Toca hacer el estilo en el mismo archivo, ya dependerá de ti que es mejor si en el tan <style> o en cada elemento. Por orden y una mejor visualización yo aconsejo la primer opción.
